# Support of different Javascript versions in browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, version

Surfing the MDC docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript), I've noticed there are quite a few versions of javascript (1.6 to 1.8.5).

I was wondering:

1. Is there any online reference for Browser / Javascript version supported ?
2. Is there any practical application for the use of different javascript versions ? According to MDC you need to do something like this to use them:

`<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"/>`

Which I haven't seen in any website IIRC.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like this version specification is deprecated now. If I try to specify version, Chrome is not loading that javascript.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**1)** Yes, on Wikipedia is a nice list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history

**2)** For websites it's not a good idea to use newer versions of Javascript, but for plugins for newer browsers it can be helpful. For example, I'm using the `forEach` function in plugins for Google Chrome

Comment: This link is no longer active

Answer (score 5):

1. Wikipedia has a pretty good chart of browser/versions, [check it out here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions).

   - Note: JavaScript isn't the only ECMAScript implementation, and JavaScript ([the standard maintained by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript)) and JavaScript the language (more general, sometimes inaccurately used, term) are not the same thing, for example IE's implementation is called [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript).
2. Not that I've ever seen in anything practical/widespread...you'd have to be doing something pretty specific/specialized for it to have any merit, imo.